# How can I get $|00\rangle |01\rangle |10\rangle |11\rangle$ entangled on IBMQ experience?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, entanglement

How can I get this situation entangled on IBMQ experience?

$$|00\rangle:\\
|01\rangle:\\
|10\rangle:\\
|11\rangle:
$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. It seems that a formating of your question is damaged. Could you please repair it?

Answer (score 4):

Quantum entanglement is a state of 2 or more qubits where the quantum state of individual qubits cannot be described. on simple terms, you cannot identify the probability in which the qubit is going to collapse to 0 or 1.

Now to answer your question, There is one thing not clear about the circuit  in your description.

What do the vectors $|00\rangle$, $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$, $|11\rangle$ represent?

Is it 2 qubit in super position (with 0 input and 2 hadamard gates) or 8 individual qubits?

If it is 2 qubits in superposition adding a simple cx gate as user KAJ226 mentioned will put it into an entangled bell state.

Assuming that it is a 8 qubit system, you just have to put the first qubit and all other qubit in individual bell states. This will put the overall system into entangled state.

[image: Circuit for 8 quibit entanglement]

This circuit will result in either all zero state or all one state as shown below.

[image: entangled state]

Answer (score 2):

I *am not sure* what you are looking for but if you are looking for how to get the state $|00\rangle$ to become an entangled state and I am assuming a maximal entangled state like a Bell-state $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $ then it is pretty simple. Just apply the Hadamard gate to the first qubit follow by CNOT gate. That is something like this:

[image]

```python
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit
%matplotlib inline

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.draw( 'mpl',style={'name': 'bw'}, scale = 1, initial_state = True)
```

Now if you want to put the state $|01\rangle$ into the same maximal entangled Bell-state as the one above, you can first flip the second qubit to get it back to $|0\rangle$ from $|1\rangle$... so now you are back the state $|00\rangle$ hence you can apply the same circuit as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

To prepare an entangled state composed of two qubits, you need to apply any controlled gates on these qubits. Such gates create a link between the qubits and as a result they are entangled. Nice examples are Bell states. These states can be prepared by putting Hadamard gate on first qubit and then CNOT on both qubits. CNOT is the controlled gate providing the link between qubits.